# why does a function that added to delegate needs to be static?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I declared a delegate:

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
```

Then i created a function that i want to add to the delegate:

```
public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Now I add the function to the delegate and call it:

```
Del handler = new Del( DelegateMethod);
handler("Hello World");
Console.Read();
```

Why when I drop the `static` from the DelegateMethod do I get an error?

Why does the function I delegate have to be static?

Comment: in what scope is that function where you are adding the handler?

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298997/why-cant-a-delegate-refer-to-a-non-static-method-when-used-in-a-static-method

Comment: Maybe you are calling the code from within a static class/function? Which I think is default for console applications in VS (your `Main` function will be static). Non static functions can only be accessed when you have an instance of the class containing them, which you do not

Comment: @musefan - thanks , i dodn't notice i was inside a console main static method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why when i drop the "static" from the DelegateMethod i get an error?

Because you are writing this code inside a static method. Given the fact that you are using `Console.Read` I presume you have put this code inside the `static void Main` method of your console application. If you wanted to *drop* the `static` keyword from the method you will need an instance of the class containing this method. Like this:

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void Del(string message);

    public void DelegateMethod(string message)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Del handler = new Del(new Program().DelegateMethod);
        handler("Hello World");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken about delegates needing to use static methods.

A method signature (return type and parameters - types, number and order) needs to match a delegate in order to be compatible with it.

From MSDN - [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx):

> Any method from any accessible class or struct that matches the delegate's signature, which consists of the return type and parameters, can be assigned to the delegate. **The method can be either static or an instance method**.

(emphasis mine)

---

When using an *instance* method as the delegate target, you must refer to an actual instance:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
Del handler = new Del(myClass.DelegateMethod);
```

Comment: Looks like Jason went on a downvote spree here, imo because he does not understand what we are trying to explain.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen - Nope, I see what he meant, though he did get a bit trigger happy with the downvotes.

Comment: But the fact that the code might be located inside a static method is not wrong, it's just that it's not the only option.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen - Yes, but the fact is that if the method is not static, you must register using an _instance_ of the class. I believe that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be static but a non-static method needs an instance. This is the very definition of non-static (instance) method. You can pass an instance method (and the instance) to a delegate like this:

```
Del handler = new Del(instanceVariable.DelegateMethod);
```

You can add instance methods to delegates in other instance method of the same class. It is assumed that the instance is this.

Keep in mind that in this way the instance will not be eligible for GC as long as the delegate instance lives. This is sometimes a reason for object leaks (some people call them memory leaks despite the fact that the leak is on a higher level and is different from C-style memory leak)

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Either what?

Comment: You say: " It needs an instance". It doesn't. It can be an instance method _or_ a static method.

Comment: Oh I meant a non-static method needs an instance. I thought it was clear. I will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> why when i drop the "static" from the DelegateMethod i get an error?

You didn't specify exactly what error you're confused by. I suspect the error you're confused by is the fact that this line will not compile if `DelegateMethod` is not `static` and you are writing the line of code in a `static` method in the containing class:

```
Del handler = new Del( DelegateMethod);
```

The reason for this is because if you don't declare `DelegateMethod` as `static`, then you need an instance to refer to the method. Given that your code is likely being written in a `static` method for the containing class, there is no implicit `this` and thus you need an explicit instance. Assuming your containing class is named `Foo`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Del handler = ne Del(foo.DelegateMethod);
```

See?

Comment: But it could also be that the code is located inside a static method, and therefore can only access other static methods. See?

Comment: Did you not read my answer carefully enough? I addressed that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here. Is the method that contains this code:

```
Del handler = new Del( DelegateMethod);
handler("Hello World");
Console.Read();
```

Also static? In that case, `DelegateMethod` must be static as well, since you can't reference a non-static method from a static one.

Comment: Not true. He could have an explicit reference to an instance of the containing class.

Comment: This is just as likely to be true as your answer. The above code might be put inside the main method of a console application for example. But hey, thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @ yvind : thank you , i don't know who downvoted this , but you have the right answer too, thank you.

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen: I'm not talking about your guess. I'm talking about this statement: "you can't reference a non-static method from a static one." Plainly and simply, it is false. `class F { void M() { } static void N() { var f = new F(); f.M(); } }` is perfectly legitimate code. Here, we have a static method accessing a non-static method.

Comment: Jason that's not correct you have a static method accessing a member of an object. That member might or might not be a method (in this case it is but you can't see that from the call site) and the original code is not accessing a member of an object but a member of the class the code is in. In that context the statement is correct

Comment: @Rune FS: No. Read the statement: "you can't reference a non-static method from a static one." Is that statement true on it's face? No, and I showed why. I showed a `static` method "referencing" an instance method. This has nothing to do with the original code. It has to do with the statement that was made, and that statement, on it's face, is false.

Comment: @Jason it's not a matter of the statement being true or false more than nonsensical. you can't reference a method in C# period. you can create a delegate. In the context of the code it's correct that the DelegateMethod is in accessible introduce a variable through which you can get access and that changes it but then the static context is referencing an object and through that accessing an instnace method. The static context is NOT accessing an instance method (directly)

Comment: @Rune FS: I think we're talking past each other because you're interpreting "reference" as if he meant it in the usual sense of that word in C#, and I'm interpreting it differently. Note that in my previous comment I put the word in quotes to indicate that I was not interpreting that word technically.